# NCurses: reading input from other terminal misses keys

Tags: c, ncurses

I am redirecting the ncurses hmi to a different, already existing terminal. While the output part works fine (and is therefore not shown here), the input misses keys which then appear in the terminal as though they had been entered without ncurses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fd = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    SCREEN *scr = newterm(nullptr, fd, fd);
    set_term(scr);
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    while (true) {
        int ch = wgetch(stdscr);
        printf("In %d\r\n", ch);    
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I create two terminals on Ubuntu and get the name of one (let's call it the 'curses-terminal') using 'tty'. This name is then used as argument when starting the above in the other terminal.
When typing in the curses-terminal, I expect the codes of the keys to appear in the other terminal without seeing anything in the curses-terminal.
Instead, I see some of the characters diffuse into the curses-terminal without their code being displayed in the other one. This happens with normal characters when typing more quickly, but it happens especially with arrow keys and ALT- combinations, where the error rate is >> 50%.
Are there any settings which I have forgotten?

Comment: Try running `tail -f /dev/null` in the target 'curses-terminal' *before* attaching your ncurses app.  I suspect both the shell already running in the terminal and your app are competing for the keystrokes.

Comment: So is there something else connected to the terminal _at the same time_ reading the characters?

Comment: Use `sudo lsof /dev/curses-terminal` (substituting the correct name for `curses-terminal`) to see which processes have the `curses-terminal` device open. Note: the`lsof` command is provided by the `lsof` package.

Comment: @G.M. Gentleman, that did it. I will use your comment as answer to my question.

Comment: The getty programs typically installed on Linux (agetty or mingetty) do not seem to respect any of the advisory locking mechanisms for terminals, and there are competing advisory locking mechanisms for terminals on Linux, so it is a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using G.M.'s hint, I was able to reliably get all input.
Run

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

in the curses-terminal before attaching the ncurses app.
Should you be tempted (like me) though to send this command from within your app after `fopen`, you may end up frustrated.